# How do i read a text file and use it to fill in the data for an array of objects?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am attempting to create a rather large program. One of the things that I need the program to do is read a text file and use it to fill in the values for multiple objects of an array. In the case of the program that i am about to post, each object of the array has three different data types that i need to fill in the values for by having my program read the text file and pull out the correct pieces of data from each line. I already know how to get my program to read a text file and print out the data line by line, but i do not know how to create a loop that will pick out specific pieces of data from a line in a text file and put them in the appropriate places for each object. The following program is a simplified version of a much larger program that is nearly complete. Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

```
package cloneCounter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class cloneCounter {
public String name;
public int age;
public double weight;

cloneCounter(String cloneName, int timeSpentLiving, double heaviness)
{
name = cloneName;
age = timeSpentLiving;
weight = heaviness;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {


cloneCounter [] clone = new cloneCounter[3];


//This is what the textfile looks like.
//Billy 22 188.25
//Sam 46 301.77
//John 8 51.22      

//code that can read and print the textfile
String fileName = "data.txt";
Scanner inputStream = null;
System.out.println("The file " + fileName + "\ncontains the following lines:\n");
try
{
  inputStream = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));//The txt file is being read correctly.
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e)
{
  System.out.println("Error opening the file " + fileName);
  System.exit(0);
}


List<cloneCounter> clones = new ArrayList<cloneCounter>();     
while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
               String line = inputStream.nextLine();
               String[] data = line.split(" ");
               cloneCounter clone = new cloneCounter(data[0],Integer.parseInt(data[1]),Double.parseDouble(data[2]));
               clones.add(clone);
           }
}


   inputStream.close();





//temporary placeholders to fill in the values for the objects until i can figure out how to import and implement the data from a text file
clone[0] = new cloneCounter ("Billy", 22, 188.25);
clone[1] = new cloneCounter ("Sam", 46, 301.77);
clone[2] = new cloneCounter ("John", 8, 51.22);



for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    System.out.println(clone[i].name + " " + clone[i].age + " " +    clone[i].weight);
}

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is separated by single space then you can do the following:

```
List<cloneCounter> clones = new ArrayList<cloneCounter>();     
while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
               String line = inputStream.nextLine();
               String[] data = line.split(" ");
               cloneCounter clone = new cloneCounter(data[0],Integer.parseInt(data[1]),Double.parseDouble(data[2]));
               clones.add(clone);
           }
```

**EDIT**: Here is the full program just copy and paste it and it will work fine (tested):

```
package cloneCounter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class cloneCounter {
public String name;
public int age;
public double weight;

cloneCounter(String cloneName, int timeSpentLiving, double heaviness)
{
name = cloneName;
age = timeSpentLiving;
weight = heaviness;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {



//This is what the textfile looks like.
//Billy 22 188.25
//Sam 46 301.77
//John 8 51.22      

//code that can read and print the textfile
String fileName = "data.txt";
Scanner inputStream = null;
System.out.println("The file " + fileName + "\ncontains the following lines:\n");
try
{
  inputStream = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));//The txt file is being read correctly.
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e)
{
  System.out.println("Error opening the file " + fileName);
  System.exit(0);
}


List<cloneCounter> clones = new ArrayList<cloneCounter>();     
while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
               String line = inputStream.nextLine();
               String[] data = line.split(" ");
               cloneCounter clone = new cloneCounter(data[0],Integer.parseInt(data[1]),Double.parseDouble(data[2]));
               clones.add(clone);
           }

   inputStream.close();






for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    System.out.println(clones.get(i).name + " " + clones.get(i).age + " " +    clones.get(i).weight);
}

}

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "Yourdata"?

Comment: Yourdata is the name of the object that you are going to use: Yourdata = new Clonecounter()

Comment: @Tom check the edit please I put all of your objects in an ArrayList

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I attempted to use what you told me to get my program to work. I made some changes to the do while loop with the hopes that i could use the variable "x" to help me fill in the data for each of the clones, however i got met with the error message Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at cloneCounter.cloneCounter.main(cloneCounter.java:51)

Comment: @Tom what changes have you made and what is the error?

Comment: How do i post a block of code as a comment on this site? Or should i update the code above to show the changes?

Comment: @Tom was it working fine with my code without modification?

Comment: No, not even after I saw the edits you made to your code. Im going to update the code again real quick to show what i have at the moment.

Comment: @Tom see my edit it worked fine on my machine without an error

Comment: It appears to be working! I'm going to try and see how it works so I can apply it to my larger program. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: I successfully got my larger code to work! I will be sure to mark your answer as accepted, thank you so much for your help!